# Is there a general convention for naming files and folders?

Tags: directory, naming-conventions, filenames, directory-structure, conventions

I'm working on a program that generates simple text files to save the state of users.

To keep things organized, I have a folder for users. Nested inside, I create a folder for each user with their ID, like this:

```
[Program Name]\currentusers\36a7781b
```

Inside of these folders I save a text file with the state of the user. At the moment I'm calling the file simply "appstate."

I have three questions:

1. Is there a convention for naming folders? E.g. currentusers, currentUsers, CurrentUsers, current_users.
2. Is there a convention for naming files? E.g. appstate, appState, AppState, app_state.
3. These are text files —should they include the .txt extension, or are they fine without it?

Answer (score 2):

In order:

1) Yes, there is a convention to name folders. End the foldername with `.d` like `foldername.d`. This is used a lot in `/etc/`, but isn't too common to use. I never use it, and I barely see it except in old "things"

2) File basenames (that's the name of the file without an extension or path) are usually minorcase, and are often separated with `-` or `_`. There are no rules. Just avoid spaces or weird symbols. Keep it alphanumerical, for your own and others' sake.

3) POSIX doesn't understand extensions, but also doesn't care if you add them. Users do, and makes it easier for users (and editors/viewers) to know how to handle files.

You said your files are text files (and if it's raw text, end them with `.txt`), but I believe what you mean is that the files are not binary files (aka readable by a human). I believe your files have some sort of data structure that is parsed by your program, forming some sort of database with folders and users... thus your files are data files (ending with `.dat` as a convention).

So... all in all:

```
MyProgram/
├── anna
│   ├── birthday.dat
│   └── name.dat
├── dog
│   ├── birthday.dat
│   └── name.dat
├── john-smith
│   ├── birthday.dat
│   └── name.dat
├── mike
│   ├── birthday.dat
│   └── name.dat
└── rachel
    ├── birthday.dat
    └── name.dat

5 directories, 10 files
```

Comment: Excellent post and really well detailed! My files are actually raw text, but they're not meant to be read by users (only I have access to them, and I won't be opening them). Should I end them with .dat anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I would go with `.dat`. At the end of the day it doesn't matter what extension (if any) you use, as long as your program knows what to search for. Also, keep in mind storing user information in plain text is both a security risk, and goes against GDPR. Consider encrypting it with some salt.